# Getter & Setter in C

Tags: c, memory, setter, getter

i'm facing a problem in C where i'm trying to use some getter and setter to share a variable between multiple source file.

I declare here my variable (ok_button) with a getter and a setter:

variable.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../libhd_src/libhd.h"

int ok_button;

void set_ok_button(int value){
    ok_button=value;
    printf("Setting ok");
} 

int get_ok_button(){
    return ok_button;
}
```

Here, when i push a button, it sets the variable to 1. (Can't upload the full code of this source file, but i see in my logs that the function set_ok_button is correctly execuded when i press (i see the printf "Setting OK" everytime i press my button))

button.c

```
#include "../libhd_src/libhd.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

 void * button_back_center_short(void *arg){
    set_ok_button(1);
    return 0;
  }
```

And here, i simply check the value of my variable with the getter function.

read.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "../../libhd_src/libhd.h"



int main(int argc, char **argv){

while(1){
      printf("Value %d", get_ok_button());
      usleep(500000);
        }
}
```

The problem is that the value shown in read.c is always "0"  even when i press my button and set the value to 1...

Does someone understand what's wrong ? Feel free to tell me if you see a better solution to do that :)

Comment: It seems like the wrong way to do it. What are the contents of *libhd.h*? You should not use global variables for this kind of things.

Comment: Where do you unset the value? (set to 0)

Comment: Since your `main()` never writes to `ok_button`, I presume the modifications that *are* done are asynchronous (in a signal handler or by hardware). In that case, `ok_button` must be *at least*  `volatile`, possibly `volatile sig_atomic_t` or lock-free atomic.

Comment: And it gets worse, it's almost 100% certain that `void * button_back_center_short(void *arg)` is the function pointer passed to `pthread_create()` you really don't want to use a global variable that way.

Comment: @iharob why do you say that? His function is probably just a callback.

Comment: @iharob, it is certainly plausible that `button_back_center_short()` is a thread function, but I'd be inclined to guess that it is just an ordinary callback function.  Any way around, however, it seems clear that it must be called from either a signal handler or a different thread.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes 100% is a lot.

Comment: Try declare ok_button in your header file

Comment: Aside?: To get safer getter/setter declare `ok_button` as static.

Comment: @PandaCool declaring `ok_button` in a header file cannot help.  The whole point is that the variable is only referenced directly from the same file in which it is declared, where no additional declaration is needed.  Personally, I'd go exactly the opposite direction, and make it `static`.  Not that that would solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You are 100% right and this time 100% is not too much.

Comment: Please post the output of the program too.

Comment: How is read.c even compiling? The symbol get_ok_button() is not defined in read.c nor do any of the includes in read.c appear to reference a file in which get_ok_button() is defined? Is there code or headers you are not revealing?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that you have multiple `set_ok_button` and `get_ok_button` functions in different files. Make sure you only have them defined in one file, and in a header add 2 lines declaring (but not defining) the functions:

```
void set_ok_button(int value);
int get_ok_button();
```